# Twig, format date SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, twig

I using Twig in a PHP application,

The PHP object that I use has an attribute called "date", got from SQL Server.

It's look like : "Mar 2 2014 12:00:00:000AM"

I try to convert it using Twig for display it, I try with | date("Y-m-d") without success :

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct() [function.DateTime---construct]: Failed to parse time string (Jun 20 2013 12:00:00:000AM) at position 20 (:): Unexpected character") in "..." at line 96.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` filter can work on `\DateTime` instances and strings that can be passed to `strtotime()`, apparently yours isn't.

You mention you're using an object that has the date property, I recommend adding a new function to it:

```
public function getDateAsObject()
{
    // should be able to parse this format: Mar 2 2014 12:00:00:000AM
    return \DateTime::createFromFormat("M j Y h:i:s:uA", $this->date);
}
```

You may need to adapt the format and the functions name for your conventions.

You can use it in your template:

```
{{ your_object.dateAsObject|date("Y-m-d" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `date('Y-m-d')`, base on the error message your object's date attribute is a type of DateTime, so use following:

```
// I assume 'object' is your object which has 'date' as the attribute
<span>Date: </span>{{ object->date->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

Check documentation for [DateTime::Format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: This is incorrect. The error says it's trying to parse a *string* with `new DateTime()` and fails.